# Как просуммировать значения табличной части документа 1с?

Tags: 1с

Как просуммировать значения столбца количество и столбца цена, чтобы в столбце сумма был результат.
то есть цена умножается на количество и в столбец сумма выводится результат[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пытался сделать так, но ничего не происходит:

```
&НаСервере
Процедура МатериалыКоличествоПриИзменении(Элемент)  
    ПокаеКолво = Элементы.Материалы.ТекущиеДанные;
    Количество = ПокаеКолво.Количество;
    Цена = ПокаеКолво.Цена;
    ПокаеКолво.Сумма = Количество * Цена;
КонецПроцедуры
```

Answer (score 3):

Свойство "ТекущиеДанные" таблицы формы доступно только "&НаКлиенте". Да и для такой простой операции незачем обращаться к серверу.

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура МатериалыКоличествоПриИзменении(Элемент)

    ТекущиеДанные = Элементы.Материалы.ТекущиеДанные;
    ТекущиеДанные.Сумма = ТекущиеДанные.Количество * ТекущиеДанные.Цена;

КонецПроцедуры
```